# How to use the return value from a called function from a foreach

Tags: java

In my function doDecoration I want to go through the list of pdfAttachments and call the function addToPdf. There the a new pdf will be created and the this one should be the new decoratedDataAsByte, so that the next element will use this new pdf as input. Currently I do not know how to do that with the foreach function.

Here is my code

```
public byte[] doDecoration(byte[] decoratedDataAsByte, RendererConfiguration config, List<IReadonlyPersistedAttachment> pdfAttachments) {

    pdfAttachments.stream()
                    .forEach(att -> addToPdf(config, att, decoratedDataAsByte));

    return decoratedDataAsByte;
}

private byte[] addToPdf(RendererConfiguration config, IReadonlyPersistedAttachment att, byte[] decoratedDataAsByte) {
    byte[] addedPdf = decoratedDataAsByte;
    if (config.getAddPdfAtBegin().contains(att.getAttName())){
        addedPdf = PdfUtils.addPdfAtBegin(decoratedDataAsByte, att.getBinary().getBinaryData());
    }
    else if (config.getAddPdfAtEnd().contains(att.getAttName())){
        addedPdf = PdfUtils.addPdfAtEnd(decoratedDataAsByte, att.getBinary().getBinaryData());
    }
    else{
        addedPdf = PdfUtils.addPdfAtEnd(decoratedDataAsByte, att.getBinary().getBinaryData());
    }

    return addedPdf;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to your problem is not to use foreach() as variables used in lambda exp should be final or effectively final.

```
    for (IReadonlyPersistedAttachment pdfAttachment : pdfAttachments) {
        decoratedDataAsByte = addToPdf(config, att, decoratedDataAsByte);
    }
    return decoratedDataAsByte;
```

You can workaround final variable problem by declaring a local effectively final variable, but I wouldn't suggest you to do this:

```
    final byte[][] finalPDFBytes = {decoratedDataAsByte};
    pdfAttachments.forEach(att -> finalPDFBytes[0] = addToPdf(config, att, finalPDFBytes[0]));
    return finalPDFBytes[0];
```

Comment: You are correct that a for loop is the easiest; but the other two ways you mention are gross (especially the instance variable one - that's downright dangerous).

Comment: Ya, I probably should have mention not to use them. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, it sounds more like a `reduce` operation rather than a `foreach`.  This is untested, but should point you in the right direction.

```
public byte[] doDecoration(byte[] decoratedDataAsByte, RendererConfiguration config, List<IReadonlyPersistedAttachment> pdfAttachments) {

    return pdfAttachments.stream()
                    .reduce(
                         decoratedDataAsByte, 
                         (att, combined) -> addToPdf(config, att, combined));
}
```

[This](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-reduce) is a pretty good tutorial on how `Stream#reduce()` works.

Comment: This will not work as he is accumulating byte[], not the items in list.

Comment: But `addToPdf` combines the current and the previous values into a new byte array, so it should work as a reducer.  I made a minor edit to my answer because it would have returned the wrong thing.

Comment: For Stream.reduce to work you need a three argument reduce as we are accumulating the item not in the list.

`byte[] reduce = pdfAttachments.stream().reduce(decoratedDataAsByte, (bytes, att) -> addToPdf(config, att, bytes), (bytes, bytes2) -> bytes2);`

Combiner part will not hit as stream is not parallel, but we need it nonetheless.